# How to Prevent Reading a Specific File with xp_cmdshell in SQL Server While Allowing it with Python Function?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to prevent the reading of a specific file using xp_cmdshell in SQL Server, but I also want to allow the file to be read using a Python function in SQL Server. So far, I've tried the following steps, but I haven't been able to solve the issue:

[First Attempt]: I modified the configuration settings to restrict file access with xp_cmdshell, but it also affected the Python function.

[Second Attempt]: I adjusted the file's access permissions, but this allowed both xp_cmdshell and the Python function to read the file.

[Third Attempt]: I attempted to read the file using Python with sp_execute_external_script, but I encountered an "Access is denied" error.

How can I configure SQL Server to prevent reading a specific file with xp_cmdshell while still allowing it to be read by a Python function? What permissions and steps should I consider?

```
1> xp_cmdshell 'type c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\web.config';
2> go
output                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Access is denied.                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

(2 rows affected)
```

```
1> EXEC sp_execute_external_script
2> @language =N'Python',
3> @script= N'import os; os.system("type c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\web.config")'
4> go
STDERR message(s) from external script:
Access is denied.
```

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info); why are you concerned about someone using `xp_cmdshell`? Only a `sysadmin` can use that function (by default).

Comment: According to the scenario, I have to do this. While the file cannot be read with `xp_cmdshell`, it should be readable with Python (I added sample commands to understand what I want to do.)

Comment: If you won't explain the problem, we can't help you... Don't complain about the *free* help you're getting if you refuse to explain the problem...

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this as described. `xp_cmdshell` is just command line. You can't set "policies" on command line operations. You can use directory permissions on the target file, but that will of course affect any mechanism trying to access the file. You could set an `xp_cmdshell` proxy account and then set directory permissions specifically for that account, but this will affect all xp_cmdshell invocations by non sysadmins (and only those made by non sysadmins). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql

Comment: You can probably use some impersonation magic in python so it runs as another user which then have access. On the other hand, if you have cmd shell access you probably can pwn the file in some other way. So why waste time doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python language extension and xp_cmdshell run under different security contexts.

[xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) runs as the SQL Server service account (when run by a sysadmin), or the configured xp_cmdshell proxy account (otheriwise).

The Python language extension runs under the [Launchpad service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/concepts/extensibility-framework?view=sql-server-ver16#launchpad) and isolated in an [AppContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/appcontainer-isolation) sandbox.

The security for the Launchpad process to access files is explained here:

"If your Python or R scripts need access to any other directory, you need give either Read & execute and/or Write permissions to the **NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad** service user account and **ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES** on this directory."

[SQL Server on Windows: Isolation changes for Machine Learning Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-server-machine-learning-services-2019?view=sql-server-ver16)

So break inheritance for the folder containing the file, and add permissions only for aministrators, NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad, and ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES.

Of course this doesn't really protect the file contents from a sysadmin, who could simply run sp_execute_external_script to get the file contents.

Comment: I gave write/read and execution permissions to the NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad service in the relevant directory. Then I removed read and write permission for the NT Service\MSSQLSERVICE account. However, when I try to read the file from the relevant directory using the Python language extension, I get the 'Access is denied.'

Comment: Did you grant access also to ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES?

Comment: oh i forgot about that. It worked thank you very much!